Android studio mirrored in physical device
I am using Android Studio when I start the app at the emulator everything works well when I start the program on a physical device everything suddenly flips[this is from the emulatorthis is from physical device](https://i.sstatic.net/AUK9Yb8J.jpg)
I tried using a different phone but it didn't work.
this is the XML code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:background="@drawable/backroundforfeed"
    tools:context=".Feed">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/recordPage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFD1DF"
        android:text="Start Activity"
        android:textColor="#636363"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.943"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.023"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/helloMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.435" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backToHome"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFD1DF"
        android:text="Log out"
        android:textColor="#636363"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/recordPage"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.127"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.023" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFD1DF"
        android:text="next activity"
        android:textColor="#636363"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.482"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.11" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/chatPage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFD1DF"
        android:text="chat"
        android:textColor="#636363"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.065"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.96" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="213dp"
        android:layout_height="119dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.743"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/presentaion" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/distanceM"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="None"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.727"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.24" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00:00"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.595"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.53" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/paceM"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-:--"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.535"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.81" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



This seems like you use a left-to-right layout on one of the devices (probably the emulator) and a right-to-left layout on the other device (probably the physical device). See here for more: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages#MirroringAddResources

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

you are giving bad constraints in your layout try to add proper constrains or use liner layout with horizontal liner layout stacked in it
just an example
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="5sp"
        android:paddingEnd="5sp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay_main_order_view_reject_accept"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_main_order_view_reject"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/black_light"
                android:text="Decline Order"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_main_order_view_accept"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginStart="3sp"
                android:layout_weight=".8"
                android:backgroundTint="#378C3A"
                android:text="Accept Order"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:icon="@drawable/accept_check_good_mark_ok_tick_svgrepo_com"
                app:iconGravity="textEnd"
                app:iconSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>


Can u explain it in more detail?

see u are using a image as background  and that image Strech according to the screen size it takes but your text view are fixed to a point on the screen when screen size changes they change there position to where they are set at so they collide with your image

that's why I would recommend to not use any background with texts as it will be hard to Aline it but to counter this you can set your text views to place them self like in center horizontal then margin start a bit

just use a background with no text and see a video on how to code for different screen sizes
